# OOP PHP — How to selectively call a specific method defined in a class' constructor?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm learning to code Wordpress Multisite the **OOP** way, and since I'm pretty new to **OOP** now I am in a situation that I can't seem to solve on my own.

Specifically, I'm creating some classes to create admin pages (both at the network and subsite level) with an **OOP** approach. Here's my simplified code:

```
class AdminPage {

    public function __construct( $args ) {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_page' ) );
    }

    public function add_admin_page() {
        add_menu_page( // arguments );
    }

}

class AdminNetworkPage extends AdminPage {

    public function __construct( $args ) {
        add_action( 'network_admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_page' ) );
     }

}
```

The code works, but as you can see I have to extend the AdminPage class with the sole purpose of changing the hook in the constructor ( I need `admin_network_menu` for admin pages at network level instead of `admin_menu`).

Is there a better way to do this? A way to have one class, put both hooks in the constructor of that class and then selectively call either one or the other?

Unfortunately, creating a new instance of the class (`$page = new AdminPage`) and then calling a method on it (e.g. `$page->add_admin_page()` ) won't work in this case, because then I get an error saying `add_menu_page` is undefined... It all has to happen in the constructor.

Comment: You can't reach into the internals of a function and just execute parts of it, no. Either you replace the entire function, as you do, or you use function parameters to influence what the function does.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for chipping in. So if I understand correctly my only option rather than overriding is passing a parameter to the constructor, e.g. 'site_level', and do one hook if its value is 'network', or the other if the value is 'subsite'. Is that correct? And which would be better practice, overriding or passing a parameter in such way?

Comment: I would pass a parameter if you know it and control it when the class is instantiated. This would allow me to avoid duplicating code unnecessarily.

Comment: *"A way to have one class, put both hooks in the constructor of that class and then selectively call either one or the other?"* -- definitely **no!** A class must have only one reason to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class AdminPage {

    public function __construct( $args, $networkPage = false ) {

        if($networkPage) {

            add_action( 'network_admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_page' ) );

        } else {

            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_page' ) );

        }

    }

    public function add_admin_page() {

        add_menu_page( // arguments );

    }
}
```

And then pass a second parameter to the class to change which action you add, e.g.

```
$page = new AdminPage($args);
$networkPage = new AdminPage($args, true);
```

Whether or not this is better than just extending the class is debatable; I personally think there's nothing wrong with your initial setup, the point of OOP isn't to create as few classes as possible - if your code make more sense as two separate classes (with one extending the other) then there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I'd probably rather go with `__construct($action = 'admin_menu')`, `add_action($action, ...)`…

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it gives an example of the other available option (passing a parameter in the constructor), which was already suggested in @deceze's comment to my question.